# Split large file in R into smaller files with a loop

Tags: r, loops, csv, large-files

I have a csv file with 12,626,756 rows that I need to split into smaller files so a colleague can open them in Excel. I want to create a loop that splits the file into files that fit within Excel's row limit and exports them as CSV files until it reaches the end (it should produce 13 files)

```
#STEP 1: load data
data <- read.csv(".../Desktop/Data/file.csv", header = TRUE)

#STEP 2: count rows
totalrows <- nrow(data)

#STEP 3: determine how many splits you need 
excelrowlimit <- 1048576 - 5
filesrequired <- ceiling(totalrows/ excelrowlimit)
```

for example:

```
csvfile 1 should contain rows 1:1048571
csvfile 2 should contain rows 1048572:2097143
csvfile 3 should contain rows 2097144:3145715
csvfile 4 should contain rows 3145716:4194287
... and so on
```

how can I write a loop statement that (1) splits by number of files needed and (2) gives a different file name to each csv export?

Comment: There’s no need to use a loop. Create a new column to indicate which file you want each row to go in. Then `dplyr::group_split` will break your df up into a list, one for each file. Then save each element of the list to your output file. All assuming you have the memory to do this.. Or `group_gy` followed by `group_walk` if you want to avoid splitting the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution expanding my comment above.  This should have a smaller memory requirement than any other solution as it does not require copying all or part of the original data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

rowCount <- 1048571
data %>% 
  mutate(Group = ceiling((row_number()) / rowCount)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  group_walk(
    function(.x, .y) {
      write.csv(.x, file = paste0("file", .y$Group, ".csv"))
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here‘s an example of how to achieve this where you can set the desired file size with `split_at`.

In the last part, you can of course change the write_csv arguments as you want, e.g. to set a path, a delimiter etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

split_at <- 5

data.frame(x = 1:19) %>%
  mutate(group = (row_number() - 1) %/% !! split_at) %>%
  group_split(group) %>%
  map(.f = ~write_csv(.x, file = paste0('file ', unique(.x$group), '.csv')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that split data by every 500 rows.You can mutate a column to lable group.Then put in for loop to write out csv according to this column.

```
#STEP 1: load data
data <- read.csv(".../Desktop/Data/file.csv", header = TRUE)

# mutate a column to lable the group
data <- data %>% mutate(Group = ceiling(1:nrow(.)/500))

# write out csv by group
for(i in unique(data$Group)){
  data %>% filter(Group == i) %>% select(-Group) %>%
    write.csv(paste0("/your/path/",i,".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will determine length of the csv, then only read in the required chunk to write at a time. This is to potentially avoid memory problems for larger files / low memory. Each file will have the same header and have a number appended to the same file name. Excel row limit is probably a little over 1m, so using that as the rows size

```
inputFile <- 'yourFile.csv'

library(data.table)

rowsDone <- 0
counter <- 0

# number of rows per file
chunkSize = 1000000

totalRows <- nrow(fread(inputFile, header = F, select = 1L))
header <- names(fread(inputFile, nrows = 0))

while (rowsDone < totalRows)
{
    chunkSize <- min(totalRows - rowsDone, chunkSize)
    print(paste0('writing rows: ', rowsDone + 1, ' to ', rowsDone + chunkSize))
    tempDF <- fread(inputFile, nrows = chunkSize, skip = rowsDone, header = F) # ignores header   
    names(tempDF) <- header
    if (counter == 0) tempDF <- tempDF[-1]
    rowsDone <- rowsDone + chunkSize
    counter <- counter + 1
    fwrite(tempDF, paste0(sub('.csv', '', inputFile), '_', counter, '.csv'))
}
```